# Hide product price on country out of GB but show only IF products have a TAG

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

currently I hide all product price for out of GB but I would like to show product price only if they have a TAG.

my code to hide product price out of GB  is anyone can help me ? please ?

```
/** hiding prices if outside of gb*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'country_geolocated_based_hide_price', 10, 2 );
function country_geolocated_based_hide_price( $price, $product ) {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Geolocation object class
    $geo_instance  = new WC_Geolocation();
    // Get geolocated user geo data.
    $user_geodata = $geo_instance->geolocate_ip();
    // Get current user GeoIP Country
    $country = $user_geodata['country'];

    return $country !== 'GB' ? '' : $price;
}
/** fin hiding prices if outside of gb*/
```

thank you

show product price for out of GB and show product price only if they have a TAG

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Faisal ! you help me so much :)

first impression, I thought it working but prices are hided on GB as well is product haven't tag.

GB = can see everything
outside of GB = can see prices only product has the tag

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code this way:

```
// This will show product prices for products with a specific tag and outside of GB

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'show_price_based_on_country_and_tag', 10, 2 );
function show_price_based_on_country_and_tag( $price, $product ) {
  
  // Get an instance of the WC_Geolocation object class
    $geo_instance  = new WC_Geolocation();
   
 // Get geolocated user geo data.
    $user_geodata = $geo_instance->geolocate_ip();
 
   // Get current user GeoIP Country
    $country = $user_geodata['country'];
    
  
  // Check if the product has the tag 'my_tag'
    $tag = 'my_tag';
    $has_tag = has_term( $tag, 'product_tag', $product->get_id() );

    // This will show price only if the user is outside of GB and the product has the tag 'my_tag'
    return ( $country !== 'GB' && $has_tag ) ? $price : '';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Faisal,   I changed this code to checked multiple tags :   // for multiple tags 'my_tags'
    $tag = array('tag1','tag2','tag3');